# How to combine multiple files in linux with delimiter seperation?

Tags: linux, file, terminal, vi, cat

I'm trying to combine multiple files to 1 file using `cat` command. 
However I wish to add a separation line like "----" in between the file contents.

Is there a way we can achieve this with cat or any other tool?

```
cat file1 file2 file3 file4 > newfile
```

Comment: More alternatives from sister sites - https://serverfault.com/q/172284/264402, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163782/92354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following command for combining multiple files with `---` delimiter.

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {print "---"}{print}' file1 file2 > newfile
```

command is copied from this post of Unix stack excahnge
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163782/combine-two-text-files-with-adding-some-separator-between

Comment: Is there a way in linux I can simplify this ? I mean make  ```awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {print "---"}{print}' ``` into a single command and then add just file names ?